# Change immediate siblings on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div and inside this rectangle boxes are appended. when i hover on a box the size of this box become larger. Now I want two boxes beside hovered box will aslo be large, but smaller than hover one. What is the solution?

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/newcss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/…;
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newjavascript.js" ></script>
        <button onclick="createElem();" >Add Neew Boxes</button>
        <div id="demo"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/newcss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>        
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newjavascript.js" ></script>  
        <button onclick="createElem();" >Add Neew Boxes</button>
        <div id="demo">                  
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

Comment: function createElem(){
    var block = '<div class="boxes" onclick=($(this).remove())>';
        block +=  '<p>Click to destroy me</p></div>';
    //alert("asdas");
     $('#demo').append(block);
}

Comment: please create it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: CSS part of Boxes: .boxes{
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 140px;
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.boxes:hover{
    
     transform:scale(1.74,1.84);
}

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xqxL2mLp/

Comment: my answer is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added 1 line css like following

```
.big{transform:scale(1.1,1.1);}
```

and using javascript

```
   $(document).on('mouseenter','.boxes', function () {
   $(this).next('.boxes').addClass('big');
   $(this).prev('.boxes').addClass('big');
}).on('mouseleave','.boxes',  function(){
    $(this).next('.boxes').removeClass('big');
   $(this).prev('.boxes').removeClass('big');
    })
```

here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/24ukqr2z/7/

if you want to add some css animation, use

```
transition: .5s;
```

demo with animation http://jsfiddle.net/24ukqr2z/8/

Comment: Here every siblings are being large. I want only previous & next sibling of hover box will be large but smaller than hover one.

Comment: @Sagar i upgraded my answer

Comment: how I specify only 12 boxes will be appended. here I use in CSS overflow:hidden, so outside of div  other appenderd boxes are invisible. how can i do this?

Comment: thanks. How can i style every appended boxes diffrent in color in background color. That means no box color will match with each other.

Comment: as your solution, when i destroy any box then append another box, in div i found two boxes in same color. I want in div every boxes will different in color. even after destroy then appended.

Comment: @Sagar how about using **.boxes:nth-child()** in css http://jsfiddle.net/24ukqr2z/18/

Comment: here which box is destroyed its color remains on remaining adjacent boxes. i want which box is destroyed this is destroyed. its color will not go to its previous or next box

Comment: I want if i hover on a box which is the first box of the row, only then the previous box of previous row will not be large.